# JavaScript Replace matching members of array compared to other array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got this task and I can't get how to replace the matches with the string "BUSTED", can you help me please. I'm new to JS. Most probably there is a way more elegant way to do this. Any help appreciated.

***You're given two arrays: one that holds every member of fCommunity and another one
that holds every possible suspect.
Replace every fCommunity member from the Suspect list with the word "BUSTED"***

```
var fCommunityMembers = ['A','B','C'];
var SuspectList = ['F','X','B','Z','Y','C','ZS','D','K','M','N'];
```

I managed to retrieve the matching members but how do I replace them in the suspect list?:

```
Array.prototype.diff = function(SuspectList) {
    var ret = [];
    this.sort();
    SuspectList.sort();
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i += 1) {
        if(SuspectList.indexOf( this[i] ) > -1){
            ret.push( this[i] );
        }
    }
    return ret;
};

var ListOfMatches = Array.from(fCommunityMembers.diff(SuspectList));

console.log( ListOfMatches );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.map()` to iterate `fCommunityMembers`. If an member is found in the `SuspectList` return BUSTED, if not return the member:

```js
var fCommunityMembers = ['A','B','C'];
var SuspectList = ['F','X','B','Z','Y','C','ZS','D','K','M','N'];

var result = fCommunityMembers.map(function(member) {
  return SuspectList.indexOf(member) !== -1 ? 'BUSTED' : member;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Judt use filter like this :

```
var ListOfMatches = SuspectList.filter(x => fCommunityMembers.indexOf(x) !== -1);
```

and a forEach loop to insert BUSTED instead of previous matched elements

```
fCommunityMembers.forEach((x,i,arr) => {
  if (SuspectList.indexOf(x) !== -1)
    arr[i] = "BUSTED";
});
```

Comment: Yes way more elegant to pick the matching members, thanks. How do I replace these common members with a string "BUSTED" in the CommunityMembers array?

Comment: @KathyBlue : answered above just now

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a function that can do the intersection between two arrays

filter can help in your case

```
var fCommunityMembers = [
    'A',
    'B',
    'C',
    'D',
    'F'
];
var SuspectList = [
    'F',
    'X',
    'B',
    'Z',
    'Y',
    'C',
    'ZS',
    'D',
    'L'
];
var suspects= fCommunityMembers.filter(function(el){
    return SuspectList.indexOf(el)>-1;
});
```

Edit #1
    To replace the values by busted, do the following:

```
var suspectsFnc = function (fc, sus) {
    var busted = fCommunityMembers.filter(function (el) {
        return SuspectList.indexOf(el) > -1;
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < fc.length; i++) {
        if (busted.indexOf(fc[i]) > -1) {
            fc[i] = "Busted";
        }
    }
    return fc;

}

var suspects = suspectsFnc(fCommunityMembers, SuspectList);
```